# Visual Studio hits unknown breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, compiler-errors

Here's what my screen looks like when I hit "Local Windows Debugger", then click the breakpoint button. The point it goes to is.....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufiH.png

My asm file says:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
.code
_Func proc
   mov ax, 1
   leave
   ret
_Func endp
end
```

And the cpp file:

```
extern "C" {
   int Func();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   Func();
   return 0;
}
```

So I'm wondering, why does this code hit this weird breakpoint. It isn't in my code...

And yes, I know what "int 3" in assembly means, that isn't what I'm wondering about. It isn't my code but it doesn't let my code run...

Comment: Where is the `ENTER` instruction matching `LEAVE`?

Comment: Your asm is nonsense, the stack pointer gets corrupted.  So the RET will resume at an arbitrary address.  Which happens to be a filler byte in a code section by accident.  Filler bytes are INT3 instructions, you can guess why.

Answer (score 0):

`.model small` is for 16-bit-MSDOS, **not** for 32-bit-Windows (Win32). Try following code:

```
.model flat
.code
_Func proc
   mov eax, 1
   ret
_Func endp
end
```